# How to aggregate multiple tabs with QUERY and document ID?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In a Google Spreadsheets document i have 60 tabs. They all have same column headings, like `date, keyword, number, url`. Tabs are named from D1 to D60. I want to organize data from all tabs into one tab, placed in another Spreadsheets document, similar to importrange. It seems `=QUERY` is able for this.

This QUERY does nearly what i need: `=QUERY({'D1'!A:Z';'D2'!A:Z';'D3'!A:Z'},...)`.

But how can i use this formula for getting data into another document? How should i reference the document ID?

I've tried something like this:

`=QUERY(importrange("1234"{'D1'!A:Z';'D2'!A:Z';'D3'!A:Z'}),...)`.
but my syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each range needs to be a standalone importrrange

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE();IMPORTRANGE(); IMPORTRANGE()}, "select *", 0)
```

Comment: Do i understand you correct: i should add into each IMPORTRANGE the same document ID and different tab? Like this? `=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("12345","B2!A2:D");IMPORTRANGE("12345","B3!A2:D"); IMPORTRANGE("12345","B4!A2:D")},"where Col1 is not null", 0)`? This formula works for me indeed, but can i shorten this formula anyhow with adding the document ID only once?

Comment: @Evgeniy yes, thats correct. this is the only way